# Cherrypy and SimpleDB with boto

Tags: cherrypy, amazon-simpledb, boto

Anyone using Cherrypy and Boto?  Any issues? Threads? Any simple examples out there?

I'm wondering where to put the initial boto.connect_sdb statement and whether I can save a domain object or have to call get_domain as I handle every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't specifically used boto with CherryPy but there are certainly examples (e.g. botoweb) of it being used in similar frameworks.  The main things about SDBConnection objects (or any connection object in boto) is that they use httplib under the covers and that is not threadsafe so you can definitely re-use and persist connection and Domain objects but make sure each thread has it's own.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thats what I needed to know, I'm using a connection pooling class to provide a connection per thread as detailed in my thread in boto-users: http://groups.google.com/group/boto-users/browse_thread/thread/7dc18d9c1677ecb5